# How to align numbers in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, align

I have a nasty overlay between the numbers and the captions of my LOF when I go beyond 10. Has anyone had the same issues?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[spanish, a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openany]{book} 

\counterwithin{table}{section}                  
\counterwithin{figure}{section}                
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newpage
{\setstretch{1.0} 
\listoffigures}
\newpage
\chapter{Chap1}   
\section{Sect1}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Images/01.png}
    \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}

...(this goes till the 12 figure)...

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Images/12.png}
    \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}
```

This is what I get:

[image: Overlayy]

It's all nice until I get to my tenth figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tocloft` to change the width of space allowed for typesetting the title numbers.

```
\documentclass[spanish, a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openany]{book} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthof{M.M.MM}}
\counterwithin{table}{section}                  
\counterwithin{figure}{section}                
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newpage
{\setstretch{1.0} 
\listoffigures}
\newpage
\chapter{Chap1}   
\section{Sect1}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}

...(this goes till the 12 figure)...

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
    \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
  \caption{XXXXX.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanksssss man!